# Proof of the Wirtinger Presentation using Van Kampen Theorem

Tags: group-theory, knot-theory, group-presentation, free-product

I have some difficulties understanding a proof of the Wirtinger presentation using the Van Kampen theorem, found in John Stiwell's "Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory".

I perfectly understand the proof except for its very end (which is crucial) : "The typical generator of $\pi_1(A \cap B)$, a circuit round a trench (Figure 161) has the form $a_ia_j^{-1}a_{i+1}^{-1}a_j$ in $\pi_1(A)$ and 1 in $\pi_1(B)$. Thus, the SVK theorem gives precisely the Wirtinger relations for $\pi_1(A \cup B)$".

(I understand we use a deform retract argument in the last sentence).

What does "has the form ... in $\pi_1(A)$" mean?

Using SVK, we compute $\pi_1(A) \star_{\pi_1(A \cap B)} \{1\}$ (since $\pi_1(B) = \{1\}$), but I don't understand how the said relations apply to the amalgamated free product.

Thank you very much!
Respectfully,

AF

[image]

Comment: Could you give the precise reference of the "Chicago University course" you mention ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It is actually from John Stillwell's "Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory". Here is a link to the said excerpt : http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Stillwell.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $\pi_1(\mathscr A)$ is a free group, with free basis $a_1,...,a_n$, and so $a_i a_j^{-1} a_{i+1}^{-1} a_j$ is an element of $\pi_1(\mathscr A)$.

The inclusion map $i : \mathscr A \cap \mathscr B \to \mathscr A$ induces a group homomorphism $i_* : \pi_1(\mathscr A \cap \mathscr B) \to \pi_1(\mathscr A)$, and this homomorphism plays an important role in the statement *and* application of Van Kampen's Theorem. In particular, part of the process of applying Van Kampen's Theorem is to take certain elements of the group $\pi_1(\mathscr A \cap \mathscr B)$, which is the domain of $i_*$, and determine their $i_*$-images in the group $\pi_1(\mathscr A)$, which is the range of $i_*$.

So to say that a certain element of $\pi_1(\mathscr A \cap \mathscr B)$ *has the form $a_i a_j^{-1} a_{i+1}^{-1} a_j$ in $\pi_1(\mathscr A)$* means that the image of that element under the group homomorphism $i_*$ is equal to $a_i a_j^{-1} a_{i+1}^{-1} a_j \in \pi_1(\mathscr A)$.